# How to Display a String like Password ****** in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way to **output/display** a user input like Password such as ******** or small circles? let say a user inputs "Maraton" how can I **represent** it as ******* in the **page** not in the `<input>`? I am not talking about input type!

Comment: This isn't really a jQuery specific question. This is more HTML and actually doing some research into the different types of input controls that are available.

Comment: You are asking what input element it is?

Comment: @Gjohn I dindt ask for <input> I am asking how to represent and display the string like password in the document!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="password" name="any" />
```

Update: Based on your comment

suppose your div where you want to show your password:

```
<div id="pass"></div>
```

Next your javascript code

```
name = "maraton";
pass="";
for(i=0;i<name.length;i++)
{
    pass=pass+"*";
}

var element=document.getElementById("pass");
element.innerHTML=pass;
```

Comment: Thanks AtanuCSE but this is not what I am asking! I need to display the string on the page not in the <input>

Comment: Your page can contain input. Anyway did you mean inside a simple div? @user3162145

Comment: Exactly! how can I display it in a div like password

Comment: let say I have a var name = "maraton"; how can I render it on page like ****** ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, See if this is what you needed @user3162145

Comment: great! Thanks alot I hope some other people who gave negative to this question at least read the post carefully! once again thanks